# Why I get different size for equal attributes types?

Tags: opengl

I trying to implement flexible shader attributes, but when I try to get them I got strange info.
This is my vertex shader:

```
    GLchar* vertexShader =
    "in vec4 position; \n"
    "in vec4 loc;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = position + loc;\n"
    "}";
```

This is my code with the help of which I get attributes info:

```
GLint i;
GLint count;

GLint size; // size of the variable
GLenum type; // type of the variable (float, vec3 or mat4, etc)

const GLsizei bufSize = 16; // maximum name length
GLchar name[bufSize]; // variable name in GLSL
GLsizei length; // name length

glGetProgramiv(shader->GetProgram(), GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &count);
printf("Active Attributes: %d\n", count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    glGetActiveAttrib(shader->GetProgram(), (GLuint)i, bufSize, &length, &size, &type, name);

    printf("Attribute #%d Type: %u Lenght: %d\n", i, type, length);
}
```

And what I get:
[image: Output info]

Why I got such strange info and how I can get size of each attribute?

Comment: Just so you know, if you load in a vec2 into a vec4 for example, then the z and w coordinates will get automatically set to 0 and 1 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from relying that indices of attributes start from zero and increments by one, but could be anything in valid index range (indices are not set in provided code).
The [length parameter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetActiveAttrib.xhtml):

> Returns the number of characters actually written by OpenGL in the string indicated by name (excluding the null terminator) if a value other than NULL is passed.

The length of `loc` is 3 and the length of `position` is 8, which appears to be correct (note different order, again do not rely on driver indexing, query it!).
*tl;dr:* You probably wanted to print `size` instead of `length`(of attribute's name).

---

Edit: further reading of linked documentation page shows that

> The size argument will return the size of the attribute, in units of the type returned in type.

The `size` is in **units of the type**, not bytes! 
Many may find this counter-intuitive, however this is how the API was designed. For sizes of types please refer to the [Type documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Type).

Comment: Oh, sorry such a dumb. Ok, I don't get size attribute's name, I wanna get attribute's size (how many bytes OpenGL was allocated to the attribute).

Comment: @АйратНасыров print *size* not *length* variable. You are getting both and printing the wrong one.

Comment: size mean how many variables can be placed to the attribute (like inside array), but I want to get size in bytes. Maybe I should get attributes info differently?

Comment: @АйратНасыров you have variable named "size", it is size in bytes use that. You used variable "length" not variable "size", if you want to know size use the variable "size". `printf("Attribute #%d Type: %u Size in bytes: %d\n", i, type, ***size***);}` **NOT** `printf("Attribute #%d Type: %u Length: %d\n", i, type, ***length***);}`

Comment: ok, once again size return how many items can attribute fit, like an array.
There some example for my opinion:
My glsl code:
 GLchar* vertexShader =
  "in vec4 position; \n"
  "in mat4 loc[2];\n"
  "\n"
  "void main()\n"
  "{\n"
  "gl_Position = position + vec4(loc[0] + loc[1]);\n"
  "}";
My output:
 Active Attributes: 2
Attribute #0 Name: loc[0] Size: 2
Attribute #1 Name: position Size: 1

Comment: And for comparison:
My another glsl code:

 GLchar* vertexShader =
  "in vec4 position; \n"
  "in float loc;\n"
  "\n"
  "void main()\n"
  "{\n"
  "gl_Position = position + vec4(loc, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
  "}";
My another output:
Active Attributes: 2
Attribute #0 Name: loc Size: 1
Attribute #1 Name: position Size: 1

Do you really think that float and mat4 has equal size in bytes? And both can be fitted in 1 byte?

Comment: @АйратНасыров great you pointed that out - even I did not read the documentation thoroughly! It is basically *count of primitives* not a size what is returned.

Comment: @wonder np :)
At least I found by myself what I can do with my problem

Comment: @АйратНасыров if you found different solution to your question, consider adding it as an answer and accepting it.

Comment: I think it's not best solution that's why I'm waiting before someone answering

Answer (score 0):

Ok, because of nobody answered this question I think I should answer it by myself.
I found "brute-force" solution. 
First of all, I need to get attribute info with that commands:

```
GLint numActiveAttribs = 0;
glGetProgramiv(shaderprogram, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &numActiveAttribs);

std::vector<GLchar> nameData(256);
std::vector<GLenum> properties;
properties.push_back(GL_NAME_LENGTH);
properties.push_back(GL_TYPE);
properties.push_back(GL_ARRAY_SIZE);
std::vector<GLint> values(properties.size());
for (int attrib = 0; attrib < numActiveAttribs; ++attrib)
{
    glGetProgramResourceiv(shaderprogram, GL_PROGRAM_INPUT, attrib, properties.size(),
        &properties[0], values.size(), nullptr, &values[0]);

    nameData.resize(values[0]);
    glGetProgramResourceName(shaderprogram, GL_PROGRAM_INPUT, attrib, nameData.size(), NULL, &nameData[0]);
    std::string name((char*)&nameData[0], nameData.size() - 1);
}
```

With this commands, you can find name of the attribute, it's type and size (**IN UNITS LIKE SIZE OF AN ARRAY**)
After that, I used simple switch to find what type is it and multiply it with attribute size.
You can find types of attributes and its sizes there: [Basic GLSL data types](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Basic_types)
or there
[OpenGL Type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Type)